# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp DispatcherProcess: com.afrivelle.moonlight, PID: 23343 java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

Tags: android

Goodday. I have been having this problem for the past few weeks. The current version of my app is on play store and is working with almost no issues then I tried to add a try catch due to a particular crash.

After then I ran into issues.
On Debug mode, the app runs well but once I generate signed APK and test, I get this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                                               Process: com.afrivelle.moonlight, PID: 23343
                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
                                                   at a.a.g.c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at b.m.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at b.m.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at b.m.al(Unknown Source)
                                                   at b.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at b.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at b.m.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at b.m.m(Unknown Source)
                                                   at b.m.v(Unknown Source)
                                                   at a.a.d.s(Unknown Source)
                                                   at a.an.d(Unknown Source)
                                                   at io.a.d.a.a.y.e(Unknown Source)
                                                   at io.a.d.a.a.y.b(Unknown Source)
                                                   at io.a.d.a.a.o.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at a.w.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at a.a.a.run(Unknown Source)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I have tried updating my dependencies all to no avail. Here are my dependencies.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.19@aar'
compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.0.8'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
compile 'io.apptik.widget:multislider:1.3'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that stacktrace I would assume you are using proguard to obfuscate your release builds.

Most likely, something is wrong with your proguard configuration, because, as you said, the debug build works just fine.

Comment: I will try adding the proguard rules for OkHttp and for Glide and find out if that fixes it

Comment: You can also see your proguard mappings inside your release build output folders and try to find what the crashing class is  `a.a.g.c.a` and hopefully get more context on the issue

Comment: So. That worked. Not sure which caused it, OkHttp or Glide. Thanks.

Comment: Where can I find the output folder?

Comment: Your `/build` directory

Comment: It would be fair to accept @RobertEstivill 's answer since it helped you resolve your issue.